# ANTLR Parser matching token not identifier

Tags: java, antlr3

I am writing a parser for SQL statements. I defined tokens for the keywords like:

```
tokens
{
CREATE = 'create';
TABLE = 'table';
YEAR = 'year';
NAME = 'name';
...
}
```

and Identifier as

```
IDENTIFIER
    :
    ( LETTER | '_' ) (NAMECHAR)*
    ;

REAL_NUMBER
  : NUMBER_VALUE  ( 'e' ( PLUS | MINUS )? DIGIT )?
  ;

fragment
NUMBER_VALUE
  : {numberDotValid()}?=> DIGIT DOT DIGIT?
  | DOT DIGIT
  | DIGIT
  ;

fragment NAMECHAR
    : LETTER | DIGIT | '.' | '-' | '_' |'%'
    ;

fragment DIGIT
  : '0' .. '9' ( '0' .. '9' )*
  ;

fragment LETTER
    : 'a'..'z'
    | 'A'..'Z'
    ;
```

I have passed the input as:

Create table emp (Table smallint not nulll);

I got an error mismatched input expecting Identifier. The error is on (Table smallint...) part. I know that tokens precedence is higher than the parser rules and it is currently matching the token Table. What is the right way to handle such types of issues?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is beacuse the token 'table' is different to 'Table' that is recognized as an identifier, note the uppercase 'T' those tokens are not the same, you could make something like:

```
TABLE : 'table' | 'Table' | 'TABLE';
```

or to avoid combinations of upper and lower cases, something like:

```
TABLE: TABLE;
fragment T:
't' | 'T';
fragment A:
'a' | 'A';
```

and so on, that's the approach used by antlr too

Comment: Alternatively you can use only uppercase letters for the lexer tokens and use a case insensitive lexer.

Comment: That would be too complex as there are lots of tokens that can be identifier in my language parser. So, doing this for all those tokens doesn't seem good.

Comment: No, that's just for key words, that's the way it is made by antrl too